# jQuery .hide() doesn't run on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically create some div elements in my container. I do it with simple function:

```
function myFunction(volume){
for(var i = 1; i<= volume; i++){
$('.container').append("<div></div>");
}
```

The problem is that generated div elements does NOT react to my jQuery .hide() function. Does anyone know why it is not working? HTML looks fine for both manualy and dynamically created elements.

I did jsfiddle, but it is kinda broken too:
http://jsfiddle.net/gQBen/

My call of .hide() function

```
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
if (run){
$(this).hide(3000, function() {
result++;
run = false;
rewrite();
});
}
});
```

Aron solve it in comments: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SM38C/1/ thanks!

Comment: how do you call the hide function?

Comment: delegate the mouseenter to the container

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SM38C/1/

Comment: Thank you Arun P Johny, you are right, that is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(".container").on("mouseenter","div",function(e){

});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Comment: In this particular case, the event can be attached to the .container div instead

Answer (score 0):

Use .onchange() instead of onclick in the option

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
myFunction(this.value);
});
```

also add value to the options

```
<option value="4" >4</option>
```

You'll also need to use event-delegation on dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','div',function() {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gQBen/3/)

Comment: works for jsfiddle(apparentl yin your demo), but not not working for calling .hide function (in your demo to)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE

The question was updated so

```
$(".container").on("mouseenter","div",function(e){
   if (run){
       $(this).hide(3000, function() {
          result++;
          run = false;
          rewrite();
       });
   }
});
```